# In Solr 7.x, how to tokenize only on comma and not on whitespace or other special character?

Tags: solr

In my schema, I have one column having comma separated list of actors. For example, Chris Pratt, Vin Diesel, Bradley Cooper, Zoe Saldana. And another column with comma separated Genre. For example Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi. In both cases I would like to tokenize only on ',' and not on white space or '-'. 
I tried creating new FieldType as suggested by another stackoverflow question,

```
<fieldType name="commaDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[,]" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It is being split on ',' but it is also splitting on whitespace and '-', resulting in tokens such as Chris,Pratt,Vin,Diesel,Bradley,Cooper,Zoe,Saldana, sci, fi.
I would like it to split only on ',' and not on any other special character.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same concept I detailed [in another recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503136/solr-query-comma-separated-fields-without-order):

```
<fieldType name="comma-separated-list" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.SimplePatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^,]+"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The SimplePatternTokenizer is similar to the PatternTokenizer, but only supports a subset of the complete regular expression syntax. This makes it faster for tasks like this. The pattern given above will split tokens on `,` (i.e. capture everything up to each `,`).

To add the field through the API, you can use:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"comma-separated-list",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer" : {
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.SimplePatternTokenizerFactory", "pattern": "[^,]+" },
        }
     }
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following tokenizer:

```
<tokenizer class = "solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern = "\ s *,:; \ s *" />
```