# SOLR query comma separated fields without order

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field which has comma separated values for e.g JSON,AngularJS and another as AngularJS,JSON and other having JSON,HTML only.

Now i have been trying to query SOLR using fq=field:(*JSON*AngularJS*), but it returns only the record with JSON before AngularJS.

How can i query SOLR so that it returns both the records having JSON and AngularJS but not considering the order.

Attaching SOLR Analysis for the field:
[image: Analysis for the field]

Query formed:
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/select?fq=field:(JSON%20AND%20AngularJS)&q=*:*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a field type that is tokenized based on `,` (i.e. each entry in your list results in a separate token). You can do this by using a [SimplifiedRegularExpressionPatternTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-SimplifiedRegularExpressionPatternTokenizer):

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.SimplePatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^,]+"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Query the index by asking for documents having both tokens present `fq=field:(JSON AND AngularJS)`.

(After update of question)

First - your field seems to be a *string* field, and not a TextField.

[image: Example definition from UI]

To add a field through the API with the correct definition:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"comma-separated-list",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer" : {
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.SimplePatternTokenizerFactory", "pattern": "[^,]+" },
        }
     }
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/schema
```

After adding a set of example documents:

```
[
      {
        "langs":"JSON,AngularJS,Microsoft Visual Basic",
        "id":"foo",
        "address":"None",
        "_version_":1606953238273196032},
      {
        "langs":"JSON,AngularJS",
        "id":"foo2",
        "address":"None",
        "_version_":1606953238277390336},
      {
        "langs":"JSON,Microsoft Visual Basic",
        "id":"foo3",
        "address":"None",
        "_version_":1606953238278438912},
      {
        "langs":"AngularJS,JSON",
        "id":"foo4",
        "address":"None",
        "_version_":1606953238278438913}]
```

And then querying using `fq=langs:(JSON AND AngularJS)&q=*:*)`:

```
  {
    "langs":"JSON,AngularJS,Microsoft Visual Basic",
    "id":"foo",
    "address":"None",
    "_version_":1606953238273196032},
  {
    "langs":"JSON,AngularJS",
    "id":"foo2",
    "address":"None",
    "_version_":1606953238277390336},
  {
    "langs":"AngularJS,JSON",
    "id":"foo4",
    "address":"None",
    "_version_":1606953238278438913}]
```

The document that didn't have `AngularJS` defined has been left out.

Comment: I tried this. Added the above lines to my managed_schema file, restarted SOLR and queried the index on this field. Says no results. If i replace AND with OR, it gives me some results but not the desired one.

Comment: Do you have examples of the content you've indexed, your query and possibly what the analysis page shows for the indexed content?

Comment: i have updated the original question with the screenshot for Analysis and the query being formed.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the Analysis page I was thinking about. Under your collection you have an option named "Analysis" in the left hand menu. It'll give you each step of how your string is processed when being indexed.

Comment: I found the issue... it was due to the String data type... i followed ur steps, and it worked. The main issue was the data type. Thanks!

Comment: one more question here. if i have to search for both JSON and AngularJS but with an OR condition, how can i return at the top those results which have both JSON and AngularJS and then other combinations?

Comment: That will be the default behavior - as long as you use `q` and not `fq`. filter queries does not affect score - they just filter the returned set of documents. `q` is your main query, and will affect score calculations.

Comment: so should i use q instead of fq?

Comment: pls ignore my last comment. With q, the scores are generated and sorted accordingly